# Updated entity is not showing

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

This is the program which I am writing in hibernate to update three fields in `emp` table in a database named as `java3` using a new thread. However after updating, it is not displaying the correct record. Instead, it is fetching the data from the cache. Please advise. `session.refresh()` is not loading the entity again from the database.

```
package mypack;

import org.hibernate.*;

public class Refresher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Main Thread Started...");
        Session session = MyFactory.getSession();
        System.out.println("Loading entity with id 1...");
        Emp e = (Emp) session.get(Emp.class, 1);
        System.out.println(e.getName() + "\t" + e.getJob() + "\t"
                + e.getSalary());
        System.out.println("Starting a new Thread...");
        Thread th = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("New Thread Started...");
                System.out.println("Modifying entity with id 1...");
                Session session = MyFactory.getSession();
                Emp e = (Emp) session.get(Emp.class, 1);
                Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
                e.setName("Kalpana Sharma");
                e.setJob("Yoga Instructor");
                e.setSalary(10000);
                t.commit();
                session.close();
                System.out.println("Entity updated, new thread completed...");
            }
        };
        th.start();
        System.out.println("Suspending main thread for 1 second...");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        System.out.println("Main Thread resumed...");
        System.out.println("Refreshing the Entity...");
        //session.flush();
        //session.evict(e);
        session.refresh(e);
        System.out.println("Refreshed state of the entity...");
        System.out.println(e.getName() + "\t" + e.getJob() + "\t"
                + e.getSalary());
        session.close();
        System.out.println("Main Thread Completed.");
    }
}
```

Output of the Program:

```
Loading entity with id 1...
Hibernate: select emp0_.EmpId as EmpId1_0_0_, emp0_.name as name2_0_0_, emp0_.Designation as Designat3_0_0_, emp0_.salary as salary4_0_0_ from Emp emp0_ where emp0_.EmpId=?
Anoop Sharma    Software Engineer   35000
Starting a new Thread...
Suspending main thread for 1 second...
New Thread Started...
Modifying entity with id 1...
Hibernate: select emp0_.EmpId as EmpId1_0_0_, emp0_.name as name2_0_0_, emp0_.Designation as Designat3_0_0_, emp0_.salary as salary4_0_0_ from Emp emp0_ where emp0_.EmpId=?
Hibernate: update Emp set name=?, Designation=?, salary=? where EmpId=?
Entity updated, new thread completed...
Main Thread resumed...
Refreshing the Entity...
Hibernate: select emp0_.EmpId as EmpId1_0_0_, emp0_.name as name2_0_0_, emp0_.Designation as Designat3_0_0_, emp0_.salary as salary4_0_0_ from Emp emp0_ where emp0_.EmpId=?
Refreshed state of the entity...
Anoop Sharma    Software Engineer   35000
Main Thread Completed.
```

Comment: In `run` method, call `session.beginTransaction()` before `session.get()` and try.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing sequence of `beginTransaction` and `get` methods,

```
...
 public void run() {
System.out.println("New Thread Started...");
                System.out.println("Modifying entity with id 1...");
                Session session = MyFactory.getSession();
                Transaction t = session.beginTransaction(); //first begin the transaction
                Emp e = (Emp) session.get(Emp.class, 1);                
                e.setName("Kalpana Sharma");
                e.setJob("Yoga Instructor");
                e.setSalary(10000);
                t.commit();
                session.close();
                System.out.println("Entity updated, new thread completed...");
            }
...
```

Comment: I have changed the code to start the transaction before session.get() however nothing changed. The output is similar as mentioned above. It is not fetching the updated entity from the database.

Comment: I have tried every possible thing to get it display the updated entity from the database however it is not displaying the updated entity from the database. Well, is there any problem with the MySql settings in phpmyadin?